# get product attributes for current product and store it in a variable

Tags: php, loop, woocommerce-offtopic

Been trying to figure out how I can get the product attributes of the current product and store it in a variable and put it in a class.

I've managed to get the product attributes, unfortunately it seems to be displaying all the products attributes to all the products I have set. Here is the code I have been working.

```
    <div id="Container" class="nine columns mixitup-container bevtools-liquor">

        <?php

        $liquor = new WP_Query( array( 
            'post_type'   => 'product',
            'product_cat' => 'liquors',
            'meta_query'  => array(
                array(
                    'key'   => '_stock_status',
                    'value' => 'instock'
                )
            )
        ) );

        if ( $liquor->have_posts() ) : while ( $liquor->have_posts() ) : $liquor->the_post();
        ?>


        //In this foreach loop, I'm trying to get all the terms for liquor-brands attributes

        <?php 
        $brand_terms = get_the_terms( $post, 'pa_liquor-brands' );
        foreach ( $brand_terms as $term ) :
        ?>

        <?php $brand_string = ''; ?>
        <?php $brand_string .= $term->slug . ' '; ?>

        <?php endforeach; ?>



        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="three columns mix product-post <?php echo $brand_string  ?>" >
        </div>


        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; else: ?>

        <?php //error message ?>

        <?php endif; ?>


        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

After running the code here is what the output looks like.

```
<div id="post-2190" class="34th-pursuit-joes-brew absolut aviation-gin bacardi botanist citadelle-gin don-papa gvine grey-goose jack-daniel johnnie-walker makers-mark monkey-shoulder pale-ale-katipunan" style="display: inline-block;" data-bound="">
</div>

<div id="post-2192" class="34th-pursuit-joes-brew absolut aviation-gin bacardi botanist citadelle-gin don-papa gvine grey-goose jack-daniel johnnie-walker makers-mark monkey-shoulder pale-ale-katipunan" style="display: inline-block;" data-bound="">
</div>
```

As you can see both products are showing all the product attributes instead of showing what is assigned to them instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `get_terms()` Retrieves the terms in a given taxonomy or list of
>   taxonomies.

What you need is

> `get_the_terms()` Retrieves the terms of the taxonomy that are **attached
>   to the post**.

So you can simply replace

```
$brand_terms = get_terms( 'pa_liquor-brands' );
```

with

```
$brand_terms = get_the_terms( $post, 'pa_liquor-brands' );
```

And that should to the trick.

You can read more about these two functions here:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/

**Edit:**
And you will also need to reset your `$brand_string` otherwise it will add terms from another posts and output them

```
$brand_terms = get_the_terms($post, 'pa_liquor-brands');
$brand_string = ''; // Reset string
foreach ($brand_terms as $term) :
    $brand_string .= $term->slug . ' ';
endforeach;

// echo $brand_string down here somewhere
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it still shows the same problem. It still shows all the taxonomies of all the products

Comment: Try resetting $brand_string just inside your loop. If you don't reset it then it will accumulate data from other posts.

Comment: Sorry but how do  you reset the $brand_string inside the loop

Comment: $brand_string = '';

Comment: Hello Nath, I've updated my code with your answer. Not sure if I did right, you can check above

Comment: Sorry wrong loop. I meant your query loop. I have also updated my answer.