# how to get woocommerce product attribute slug

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to get product attribute slug. I have used below code but it display name.

```
echo $_product->get_attribute( 'pa_color' );
```

I am working on woocommerce/cart/cart.php file in theme folder.

Also I checked this is coming in anchor url of product image in cart page but not getting it

**anchor url**: https://example.com/productos/sweatshirt/?attribute_pa_color=aa2757&attribute_pa_talla=m

I am working on this from today morning but I have not get success. Please guide.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got this....

To get slug use:

```
$attributes = $_product->get_attributes();
$pa_color = $attributes["pa_color"];
```

Thanks to all for helping me.

Comment: This returns a [WC_Product_Attribute](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_Attribute.html). 
So the correct answer to this question is to write (after your code): `$pa_color->get_slugs()`
And if you want the first slug - as you normally would: `$pa_color->get_slugs()[0]`.

Answer (score 4):

```
$att=$_product->get_attribute('pa_color');

$values = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pa_color', array( 'fields' => 'all' ) );
foreach($values as $val){
  echo "<pre>";
  var_dump($val->slug);
  echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: I used this code, its showing all attributes but i need only one respective attribute.

Comment: @AbiSharma - I just found something related to what you are searching for in below question....just display variable value using below thread implementation.
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/240283/get-product-attributes-for-current-product-and-store-it-in-a-variable

Answer (score -1):

Use next:

```
$attribute->get_name()
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit why this is a solution? You should post answers here and not only solutions :)